# Searching for people from user input

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm pretty new to Java, and I've been having a problem searching for a person in my Binary Tree. I want it so that what number is entered will bring up that person (User ID, Name etc.).

So far, this is what I have:

```
BinaryTree Tree = new BinaryTree();
BinaryNode NodeAt;

int TypeIn;
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);   

Person PersonA = new Person(1,"PersonFirstName","PersonLastName","PersonPassword");
//Above repeated but PersonA becomes PersonB etc.

Tree.Insert(PersonA);
//Above repeated but PersonA becomes PersonB etc.

Tree.InOrder(MyTree.gRoot());

TypeIn = user_input.nextInt()

if (TypeIn == 1) {
     NodeAt = MyTree.Find(PersonA); 
     System.out.println("NodeAt.gKey()); 
}
// Repeat for other people (1 becomes 2, PersonA becomes Person B etc.)
```

There is also a Person class that is linked to this.

I was mostly curious if there is an easier or more suitable way to show the users. I don't really want to copy the if statement `(if (TypeIn == 1))` and change the TypeIn to 2, 3, 4, 5 etc and PersonA to PersonB. It does work that way, just want to try and be neater and learn other ways.

Comment: Please try to use standard Java naming conventions. This means camelcase for variables and methods and upper camelcase for class names (for instance `int typeIn;`, `BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();`, `tree.insert(personA);`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement instead of repeating the ifs

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a method in the BinaryTree class like this:

```
/**
 *
 * Search and returns the first node in the tree whose id match the passed id
 *
 * @param id of the searched person
 * 
 * @return Person the found person 
 *                or the special value Person#UNKOWN_PERSON if no matching id found
 */
public Person findById(int id) {
     // ...


}
```

In you main code, you would have:

```
Person p = MyTree.findById(user_input.nextInt());
```

Here is the definition of UNKNOWN_PERSON:

```
public class Person {
    public static final Person UNKNOWN_PERSON = new Person(...);

    // ...
}
```